# grouping or merging? dataframes pandas python

Tags: python, merge, pandas, grouping

Another question on grouping items in pandas. Currently I am grouping them using the merge function with the stack function in  the following code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['SS', 'SS', 'SS', 'DD', 'DD', 'FF'],
                'No.' : ['323', '12', '21', '334', '44', '55'],
                'Res' : ['O', 'E', 'O', 'E', 'E', 'O']}).set_index('Type')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['SS', 'SS', 'TT', 'DD', 'FF'],
                'No.' : ['43', '77', '98', '352', '51'],
                'Res' : ['O', 'O', 'E', 'E', 'O']}).set_index('Type')
Merged=concat([df,df2], axis=0, keys=['Sample1','Sample2']).stack()

print Merged
```

---

```
         Type     
Sample1  SS    No.    323
               Res      O
               No.     12
               Res      E
               No.     21
               Res      O
         DD    No.    334
               Res      E
               No.     44
               Res      E
         FF    No.     55
               Res      O
Sample2  SS    No.     43
               Res      O
               No.     77
               Res      O
         TT    No.     98
               Res      E
         DD    No.    352
               Res      E
         FF    No.     51
               Res      O
```

Is there a way to group so I can get the Results similar to the following way:

```
      Sample1  Sample 2
      No. Res  No.  Res
Type         
SS    323   O   43   O
       12   E   77   O
       21   O
DD    334   E  352   E
       44   E
FF     55   O   51   O
TT              98   E
```

Comment: Where are you getting concat from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried was almost correct, you only needed a `axis=1` in `concat` (and no stack). But the **problem** with your dataframe is that you have a **non unique index**, so `concat` cannot know how to concatenate the two dataframes along that axis (you have eg multiple 'SS').
One way is eg to add a second level to the index to make it unique (this only works with pandas 0.13, see below for workaround for older version):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()
df2['count'] = df2.groupby(df2.index).cumcount()
df = df.set_index('count', append=True)
df2 = df2.set_index('count', append=True)
```

So the dataframe looks like:

```
In [64]: df
Out[64]:
            No. Res
Type count
SS   0      323   O
     1       12   E
     2       21   O
DD   0      334   E
     1       44   E
FF   0       55   O
```

And then you can just concat the two with `axis=1` and the `keys` you provided:

```
In [65]: pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1, keys=['Sample1','Sample2'])
Out[65]:
           Sample1      Sample2
               No.  Res     No.  Res
Type count
DD   0         334    E     352    E
     1          44    E     NaN  NaN
FF   0          55    O      51    O
SS   0         323    O      43    O
     1          12    E      77    O
     2          21    O     NaN  NaN
TT   0         NaN  NaN      98    E
```

You can always drop the `count` again with `merged.index = merged.index.droplevel(1)`.

But of course, whether this is a good solution depends on the nature of you data and what you want to do with it further.

---

Note: `cumcount` is a new method only available in master (released soon as 0.13), at the moment you can achieve the same with:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['count'] = df.groupby('Type').apply(lambda x : pd.Series(np.arange(len(x)), x.index))
df.set_index(['Type', 'count'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a column multiindex to get the data in exactly the format you require:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['SS1', 'SS2', 'SS3', 'DD1', 'DD2', 'FF1'],
                'No.' : ['323', '12', '21', '334', '44', '55'],
                'Res' : ['O', 'E', 'O', 'E', 'E', 'O']}).set_index('Type')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['SS1', 'SS2', 'TT1', 'DD1', 'FF1'],
                'No.' : ['43', '77', '98', '352', '51'],
                'Res' : ['O', 'O', 'E', 'E', 'O']}).set_index('Type')


#Add multi index to the two dataframes
df.columns = [["Season 1"]*2, list(df.columns)]

df2.columns =  [["Season 2"]*2, list(df2.columns)]

#Join on their row index
df.join(df2)
```

Comment: The problem with join is that you end up with duplicate rows because of the non-unique index.

Comment: Yep - I had to add numbers to the type index to make it work, which isn't very elegant.  On the other hand, it allows you to control which records within a type align in a row.

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't seen that. That's a little bit similar to what I did, add a column with these numbers instead of to the lables themselves. Once you have a unique index (with mine or your approach), both approaches (mine or yours) yield the same result.